# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) error

Tags: php, mysql, web

My form is consistently getting an error when I try to submit.

Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2).

I'm on windows by the way.
https://web.njit.edu/~jsd42/form/form1.php

Comment: ive had this error in the past. In my case it was a simple problem of changing the database host from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` or vice versa. Give it a try.

Comment: there's no code (php/mysql) to support this question; it's unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your MySQL user and your php mysqli_connect() to both use "localhost" as the connecting host.

Edit:
If it is a remote server instead of "localhost" you will need to use the IP of the mysql server and ensure that the user you are logging in as has permission to connect externally.

Comment: but i have to connect to my schools database

Comment: So instead of "localhost" you will need to use the IP of the mysql server and ensure that the user you are logging in as has permission to connect externally.